# Excel VBA: Copy cell value to cmd

Tags: excel, cmd, vba

I never had a pleasure to work with VBA and I'm looking for some advice or solution with adding cell value to cmd.
I wish I could add my loop value at the end of specified command

e.g
execute cmd with:

```
java -cp D:\Automation_Mobile.jar utils.Loop D:\MobileLogin.xml %value from cell here%
```

by clicking a button.

I know how to copy/paste cells, worksheet or files but I can't find how to add a cell value to already specified command

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Shell "CMD /K java -cp D:\Automation_Mobile.jar utils.Loop D:\MobileLogin.xml", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

I will be grateful if somebody could explain or sent me any solution ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the cell's sheet (e.g. `Sheet1`) and address (e.g. `A1`) you can get the value with:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

So your code becomes:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim strBaseCmd As String
    Dim rngParameter As Range
    Dim strParameter As String
    Dim strCmd As String

    ' base command
    strBaseCmd = "CMD /K java -cp D:\Automation_Mobile.jar utils.Loop D:\MobileLogin.xml"

    ' get a cell from a sheet in this workbook
    Set rngParameter = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    strParameter = rngParameter.Value

    ' add parameter to command
    strCmd = strBaseCmd & " " & strParameter

    ' run command
    Shell strCmd, vbNormalFocus


End Sub
```